# Scraping a webpage with python to get onclick values

Tags: javascript, python, onclick

First of all I have to say: be patient with me because I am not familiar with the argument that I am going to illustrate you.

I'd like to download the intraday historical values of some equities on Frankfurt Boerse website. Let me take this equity for example: http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/equities/adidas+ag+DE000A1EWWW0/price+turnover+history/tick+data#page=1

As you can see there are two options: trades on Frankfurt and trades on Xetra. I'd love to download the latters. I tried to scrape the data but my knowledge of python is very poor.

How can I 'select' the desired onclick option?

Thanks in advance for your replies. Regards

Ps: For your information, I noted the following fact inspecting the Xetra element: it changes value when I move on to next page and if I come back the value is again different. Here an example: first time on page 1 I got

```
a onclick="d39081344_fkt_set_par('6');d39081344_fkt_set_active(this);" class="brs_d39081344_li current last"
```

, then I moved on to page 2 and I got

```
a onclick="d51109535_fkt_set_par('6');d51109535_fkt_set_active(this);" class="brs_d51109535_li current last"
```

and coming back to page 1 I got

```
a onclick="d96086211_fkt_set_par('6');d96086211_fkt_set_active(this);" class="brs_d96086211_li current last"
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to look at what calls are made when you navigate through the pages. Your browser's network analysis tool is invaluable for this. When I go from page to page, a POST is made to 'http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/parts/boxes/history/_tickdata_full.m with data about the request.

Then the goal is to replicate and loop the requests using python. Here is code to get you started:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/en/parts/boxes/history/_tickdata_full.m', data={'component_id':'PREKOP97077bf9dec39f14320bf9d40b636c7c589', 'page':"3", 'page_size':'50', 'boerse_id':'6', 'titel':'Tick-Data', 'lang':'en', 'text':'LOcbaec84ecad1b94ad2fd257897c87361', 'items_per_page':'50', 'template':'0', 'pages_total':'50', 'use_external_secu':'1', 'item_count':'2473', 'include_url':'/parts/boxes/history/_tickdata_full.m', 'ag':'291', 'secu':'291', })
print r.text #here is your data of interest, it still needs to be parsed
```

That is the general idea. You would then put that in a loop, adding one to the `page` parameter each time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I am able to download the data I want. Thanks again!